# Writing a Scheme interpreter with FPC: Allocation and Pointers

Tags: delphi, scheme, pascal, freepascal, sicp

Being a historian, writing a [Scheme interpreter in FPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164783/writing-a-scheme-interpreter-with-fpc-recursive-data-structures) turns already in the first stage out to be a serious task for me. :) I am following the blog of Peter Michaux, [who showed how to do it in C](http://michaux.ca/articles/scheme-from-scratch-introduction) (there is also a translation to [Ada](https://github.com/fitzgen/ada-scheme), which may be helpful for Pascal).

Consider these two functions in C from Michaux’s work (v 0.1):

```
object *alloc_object(void) {
    object *obj;

    obj = malloc(sizeof(object));
    if (obj == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return obj;
}

object *make_fixnum(long value) {
    object *obj;

    obj = alloc_object();
    obj->type = FIXNUM;
    obj->data.fixnum.value = value;
    return obj;
}
```

As far as I understand (just basic reading knowledge in C), the constructor `make_fixnum` returns a pointer to a struct (tagged data of type fixnum); for the constructed object, memory has to be allocated (thanks @David Heffernan for his [point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164783/writing-a-scheme-interpreter-with-fpc-recursive-data-structures/14164933#14164933) yesterday).

This is my translation to FPC so far, which compiles without any error:

```
program scheme;

type
   TTag = (ScmFixnum);
   PScmObject = ^TScmObject;
   TScmObject = record
      case ScmObjectTag: TTag of
         ScmFixnum: (ScmObjectFixnum: integer);
      end;

var Test: PScmObject = nil;

procedure AllocateObject(x: PScmObject);
begin
    new(x);
end;

function MakeFixnum(x: integer): PScmObject;
var
   fixnum: PScmObject = nil;
begin
   AllocateObject(fixnum);
   fixnum^.ScmObjectTag := ScmFixnum;
   fixnum^.ScmObjectFixnum := x;
   MakeFixnum := fixnum;
end;

begin
   Test := MakeFixnum(1);
   writeln(Test^.ScmObjectTag);
   writeln(Test^.ScmObjectFixnum);
end.
```

However...:

```
$ ./test 
Runtime error 216 at $080480DD
  $080480DD
  $08048117
  $08063873
```

I suspect, there is a serious flaw how I am using and referencing pointers.

Many thanks to anybody who helps me to understand how this pointer and memory stuff works (references to FAQ’s, papers etc. are welcome as well).

Comment: AllocateObject really should be a function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your AllocateObject function is wrong. It is creating a new object in the variable x, but it does not pass the created object to the calling function, since it is called by value. If you change the calling convention it works:

```
 procedure AllocateObject(out x: PScmObject);
 begin 
    new(x);
 end;
```

You can see the if you look at the the fixnum variable in the debugger, it stayed nil.

---

---

Unrelated to your question, I do not think it is a good idea to use records in an interpreter. It turns soon in a memory managing nightmare (at least that happened in an interpreter I wrote when it came close to 20 kloc, and I had to replace records as follows:)

Instead of your record

```
 PScmObject = ^TScmObject;
 TScmObject = record
    case ScmObjectTag: TTag of
       ScmFixnum: (ScmObjectFixnum: integer);
    end;
```

you can use classes, like:

```
TScmObject = class()
  function Tag: TTag; virtual; abstract;
  function Fixnum: integer; virtual; abstract;
end;
TScmObjectFixNum = class(TScmObject)
  function Tag: TTag; override;
  function Fixnum: integer; override;
private
  value: integer;
end;

function TScmObjectFixNum.Tag: TTag;
begin
  result := ScmFixnum; 
end;
function TScmObjectFixNum.Fixnum: integer; 
begin
  result := value; 
end;
```

Then you create it easily with

```
 var x: TScmObject;
 x := TScmObjectFixNum.create() ;
 if x.tag = scmfixnum (* or x is TScmObjectFixNum *) then
    ... x.scmfixnum ...
 x.free
```

If there are no circular references in your scheme implementation, you can even use interfaces. Then it is reference counted and automatically freed:

```
IScmObject = interface
  function Tag: TTag;
  function Fixnum: integer;
end;
TScmObject = class(TInterfacedObject, IScmObject)
  function Tag: TTag; virtual; abstract;
  function Fixnum: integer; virtual; abstract;
end;
TScmObjectFixNum = class(TScmObject)
  function Tag: TTag; override;
  function Fixnum: integer; override;
private
  value: integer;
end;



 var x: IScmObject;
 x := TScmObjectFixNum.create() ;
 if x.tag = scmfixnum (* or x is TScmObjectFixNum *) then
    ... x.scmfixnum ...
 //x.free no longer necessary (or allowed)!
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort! Your implementation with classes seems to be straightforward, I will try that. Just one further question: What is exactly meant by »circular references« you talked about?

Comment: With interface the object is automatically deleted when no reference points to it. So you can write `var a,b: ISomething; a := TSomething.create; b := a; a := nil;` and have the only pointer to the object in b . If you write `b := nil;` the object is destroyed. | But if there is a  circular reference, i.e. something pointing to the object and the object pointing to the something that does not work, since the references will never be all nil. E.g. if you have implemented cons, you could have `b = cons(b, b)`, then b is pointing to itself and never destroyed.(but if your cons make a copy its ok)